# Where to get samples of subauthentication packages for Windows 7?

Tags: c++, security, visual-c++, authentication, windows-7

I was trying to create a subauthentication package for Windows 7. But no samples are available.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231793(VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The authentication packages provided with Windows support customization using subauthentication packages. A subauthentication package is a DLL that supplements or replaces part of the authentication and validation criteria used by the main authentication package. For example, a particular server might supply a subauthentication package that validates a user's password with a different algorithm or specifies workstation restrictions in a different format.

You can see [this online sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231793%28VS.60%29.aspx)
or see the SubAuth sample installed with the [Platform Software Development Kit (SDK)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4237)
.